# Cannot Update Cell Values in R Raster

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I have a list of cells within a raster for which I would like to change the value of the cells (while leaving all other cells alone). I have copied some test (reproducible) code below that I have managed to get working. It generates a test raster, and, for the cells defined in vals, changes the cells to a value of 50.

```
# My List of Cells That Require Changing
vals<-c(2,4,6,10,15,27)

#Example Raster
r <- raster(ncol=6, nrow=6)
r[] <- 1:ncell(r)
plot(r)


#Change Cell Values
r[r%in%c(vals)] <- 50
plot(r)
```

So far, so good. However, when I apply the same code to my real life data I cannot change the cell values. The code runs absolutely fine (no error messages at all) but the cell values simply don't change.

My first question is whether anyone else has come across this issue before? My second question is: what's the best way of me providing my real-world example to the StackOverflow community so that maybe someone could help me troubleshoot the issue? I fear that without using my dataset, this issue will remain unresolved. I have read that using r[r%in%c(vals)] <- 50 can be unstable memory-wise for large rasters but I'm not sure this is the case with my example (my raster is an image of Jamaica and only contains 4185 cells and when running the code, I haven't noticed any spikes in RAM usage).

Any assistance you can provide will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this alternative approach:

```
rcl <- cbind(from = vals, to=50)
x <- reclassify(r, rcl)
```

If that does not work either, it would suggest that the values you want to replace are not actually in your data

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for your reply. I have tried the above and it doesn't work- the code runs with no errors but my plot doesn't display the changes. I generated my list of cells (vals) from the raster I am trying to update. Therefore, I can't think why the cells I am trying to update values for aren't in my raster.

Comment: Some extra information may be helpful here.
I used cellFromXY to flag all cells that contained a species occurrence record. It is these cells that I am attempting to change. The ultimate goal is to then use the 'distance' function to compute a distance surface.

Comment: `cellFromXY` gives you cell numbers, not cell values. If you have cell numbers, you can do `r[cellnumbers] <- 50`

Answer (score -1):

The problem could also be the class of your data! I had the exact same problem, and it turned out that the value that I wanted to change wasn't an integer,

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).